# MVC TTFB is too long

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

We have an MVC website. There is a registration form with several steps. There are buttons 'Next' and 'Back' to move back and forth. The 'Next' validates the form using unobtrusive validation and moves to the next step. The 'Back' ignores validation errors, submits the form and does a 302 redirect to previous step. For some reason one of the steps takes too much time to first byte (16-30 seconds):
[image: waterfall]
[image: waterfall2]

What's interesting, it only happens when I submit the empty form. If the form is filed in, there is no wait at all. 
[image: form on step 3]

Does anyone know what could cause this behavior?

Comment: You're asking people to guess what your code does. Have you tried debugging your application? What's going on in those 17 seconds? What you posted doesn't provide any information, even the URL is missing.

Comment: `it only happens when I submit the empty form` this could be due to faulty exception handling code that throws due to the invalid form data but still retries until a timeout expires.

Comment: 1. I can't post all the code for various reasons.
2. IDK, I set the breakpoint on the first line of the method and it is only reached after the 17 seconds.

Comment: Of what method? Did you try debugging? Did you try pausing the debugger during those 17 seconds? Where did execution stop? Only you know what your code does.

Comment: `this could be due to faulty exception handling code`

Yes, this seems like the cause. Thanks a lot.